# Processing a string with the null character

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a text file full of strings (computer paths) which I want to process by replacing every backslash with an underscore, in addition to replacing every number ( integer or float) with an underscore as well, the original string looks like that : 
`string = "\Software\Microsoft\0\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\Cache"`

Usually, I could replace easily the backslash with the following command: 
`string=string.replace('\\','_')`
and apply some regular expressions such as: `'(\d(?:\.\d)?)'` to replace the numbers. 
However in my case I couldn't do either, because python recognise always `'\0'` as a null character and `'\5.0'` as ENQ, in fact any number follow the backslash will be treated the same way as well.

Any suggested way to replace them ? 
e.g. is there a way to convert my string to raw string as a start ?

Comment: I suspect the real string looks like `string = r"\Software\Microsoft\0\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\Cache"`

Comment: The string should not look like that. It should look like: `string = "\\Software\\Microsoft\\0\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\5.0\\Cache"`. You **should escape** the backslash...

Comment: you could use the raw prefix: `string = r"\Software\Microsoft\0\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\Cache"` and the same with your expressions. `r"\0"` works fine for instance.

Comment: can you replace on string '\0' and '\5' ?

Comment: my string actually looks like this "\Software\Microsoft\0\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\Cache", how can I add the escape backslash or anything else .. I cannot modify the original text at all !

Answer (score 0):

Always remember: Backslash(`\`) escapes special characters. If you want to use the backslash itself, you need to escape it too. Your string should look like this:

```
string = "\\Software\\Microsoft\\0\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\5.0\\Cache"
```

Comment: If you don't control it, you shouldn't have it as plain text in you code, should you?

Comment: I believe that is exactly the problem OP is saying, with it as plain text as a string Python is auto-funk-ating it. I can't reproduce his exact problem however.

Comment: It would be easier if it looks like that or I can change it to something like that .. but how can I change it in python this is my question ? I have all the text as a text file and I thought I can read it and modify it using python but I couldn't !